# Uppercase code completion in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

Can I configure Netbeans to autocomplete code when I type the capital letters?

E.g. `Z` displays completion list starting with the letter `Z`, e.g. `Zend_…`, then I type `vh`, and the list is limited to this items, which have the capital letters `Z`, `V`, `H` in it, e.g. `Zend_View_Helper_…`.

Does Netbeans support this bevaviour?

Comment: Seems that it is not possible with current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in current version. Switch to Eclipse or Zend Studio if you need this feature.